# QFileDialog create a filter for all supported image formats

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qbytearray

I would like to open a `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` with all supported image formats (all file types that I could used to instantiate a `QIcon`)

I already know that I can get all supported image formats with `QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()`.

What confuses me is that `QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()` returns a list of `QBytesArray`, and I'm not sure how to convert this simply into a list of `str`.

```
class ProfileImageButton(qt.QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIconSize(qt.QSize(100, 100))
        self.clicked.connect(self._onClick)
        self._icon_path = None

    def _onClick(self, checked):
        supportedFormats = qt.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()
        print([str(fo) for fo in supportedFormats])
        # this prints: ["b'bmp'", "b'cur'", "b'gif'", "b'icns'", "b'ico'", "b'jpeg'",

        fname, filter_ = qt.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent=self,
            caption="Load a profile picture",)
            # filter=???????????)   #     <--- TODO

        if fname:
            self.setIcon(qt.QIcon(fname))
            self.setIconSize(qt.QSize(100, 100))
            self._icon_path = fname

    def iconPath(self):
        return self._icon_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the `QByteArray` to `bytes` using the `data()` method, then the bytes to `string` using `decode()`. Then it is only concatenated to obtain the required format.

```
text_filter = "Images ({})".format(" ".join(["*.{}".format(fo.data().decode()) for fo in supportedFormats]))

fname, _ = qt.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
    parent=self,
    caption="Load a profile picture", 
    filter=text_filter
)
```